# After the license change, we won't be able to adapt old answers!

Tags: discussion

When [Stack Exchange changes to the MIT license](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272956/a-new-code-license-the-mit-this-time-with-attribution-required?cb=1), [we won't be able to adapt answers from old code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273564/177681) (except our own, or with the owner's permission).

[And that's terrible!](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AndThatsTerrible) After all, adapting old answers for new challenges is a way to help the community grow.

I guess we could go back to all our old answers, and put a note authorizing its use under MIT, but this is a lot of work.

What should we do? What *can* we do?

Answer (score 5):

### There's nothing to do right now.

It's not clear what, if anything, is going to happen to the license. As you can see, the proposal has a total score of -266, with Stack Exchange saying that they'll be back with more discussion. So it's clear that, at least for now, we're not switching to MIT.

If something changes, we can discuss the ramifications on our community once things are definite.